# Why part of points doesn't snap?

Tags: inkscape, snapping

I have a vector shape. Some of vertexes are snap to guides, some not:

[image]

In snapping, all types of vertexes are turn on:

[image]

All vertexes looks similar:

[image]

What is going on here?

**UPD.** With zooming (all the same):

[image]

It's looks like "snap to the target that is closest to the mouse pointer" helps, but i don't like this behavior.

[image]

Comment: It is not really possible for a computer to be a mind reader. The problem is that when you have enoug points then the computer starts to act as if it was not snapping at all (althought it is). Simply suddenly moving cursor by a subpixel will snap it somewhere else. You would then interpret this as no snapping.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there are just too many snap targets. There is an option in the Inkscape preferences to only snap to the target that is closest to the mouse pointer (Edit > Preferences > Behavior > Snapping). Does that help? The snap target will then even be highlighted.

Use Alt+Click to be able to grab the selected object in any place you want.

Comment: It's also handy to zoom in to the area desired, to enable the system to better determine the desired node for snaping.